# properties of households from individual data

Tags: stata

I want to create new variable `HHage` which is the age of head of household reported by HID. In the dataset, the head of household is coded by `P1`. The dataset looks like this:

```
Personid   HID    Age   
P1         100    12    
P2         100    45
P1         101    16
P1         102    35
P2         102    24
P3         102    26
```

I tried the `egen` command but I get an error pertaining to numlist. The command I used was:

```
egen hhage = anyvalue(age), values(integer 1,2 to 26)
```

Comment: I changed the title. The use of `egen`'s `anyvalue()` function here is  only a distraction, as it has no real bearing on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
// create the example data
clear
input ///
str2 Personid   HID    Age
P1         100    12
P2         100    45
P1         101    16
P1         102    35
P2         102    24
P3         102    26
end

// check whether there is only 1 household head per household
bys HID : gen byte flag = -(Personid == "P1")
bys HID (flag): replace flag = sum(flag)
assert flag == -1
drop flag

// create hhage
gen hhage = Age if Personid == "P1"
bys HID (hhage): replace hhage = sum(hhage)
list , sepby(HID)
```

Answer (score 2):

The excellent answer from @Maarten Buis explains that you can do this without `egen`. This answer focuses on using `egen` for this kind of problem.

What is allowed as a *numlist* is a minor issue here; the major issue is that the `egen` function `anyvalue()` is of little help. Its documentation explains that

`anyvalue(`*varname*`), values(`*integer numlist*`)` may not be combined with `by`.  It takes the value of *varname* if *varname* is equal to any integer value in a supplied *numlist* and is missing otherwise.

This would be legal syntax

```
egen hhage = anyvalue(age), values(1/26)
```

but Stata would copy ages 1 to 26 to the new variable and ignore the others, observation by observation, regardless of household and who is head of household. That is not what you want.

One `egen` solution for this might be

```
egen hhage = total(age * (Personid == "P1")), by(HHID)
```

The expression `Personid == "P1"` evaluates to 1 when true and 0 when false. So the `age` of the household head appears in the total and other values of `age` are ignored in so far as they contribute 0 to the total.

The `by()` option is undocumented but will work. Stata encourages you to do this instead:

```
bysort HHID : egen hhage = tota(age * (Personid == "P1"))
```

This solution assumes that

1. `Personid` is a string variable. If it is a numeric variable, the expression `Personid == "P1"` should be replaced by something like `Personid == 1` using 1 or whatever other integer code is appropriate.
2. There is one head of household per household. That can be checked directly by something like

   ```
   egen hhcount = total(Personid == "P1"), by(HHID)
   ```

See also http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 for a review of technique in this territory.

Note that in principle you could go something like

```
    egen work = anyvalue(age) if Personid == "P1", values(0/200)
```

allowing any `age` imaginable so long as the person is head of household. Then you could fix that by

```
    egen hhage = total(work), by(HHID)
```

However, I can see no point in that solution.

Comment: If you want to thank my friend and co-author Maarten Buis, he gave the other answer.